# Finding the two suitable points among $n$ points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, slope

I have $n$ points in the $xy$-plane; $(x_1,y_1), \dots , (x_n,y_n)$. I want to find the following:

- the two points that form a line with greatest slope.
- the two points that form a line with least slope.

I do not know any way except to check all $C_2^n$ combinations.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with a computer-science mindset?

Comment: how are you considering the negative slopes ?

Comment: I think that there is no way to know, that depends on the points $(x_k,y_k)$

Comment: @thebestmagician No, just a pure maths way.